# Compare Projected & Actual figures using conditional fomating

Tags: excel

I am looking for help.

I have a spread sheet with projected figures and on another work sheet actual figures. The projected figures have been styled green low through to red high.

On the actual spread sheet I want a rule that compares the actual figure with the projected figure and the respective field to be red or green if the actual is more than or less than the projected.

This sounds simple but for me who is getting back into the swing of excel from a hiatus, is something I am struggling to do without having to create individual rules per cell.

All help appreciate, I image there a few ways of doing this.

Comment: Select the range you want the rule to apply to, and then enter the formula for the highlighted cell (which should be the first one that you clicked on). For example, if the rule is in G2:G100 and it's looking at F2:F100 for a comparison, you might use the rules `=G2<F2` and `=G2>F2`. The rule for each remaining cell in the range will be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks jsheerna the tables are on two different worksheets so the second worksheet needs to reference cells in another work sheet, the above wouldn't work in this instance s the projected and actual are separate

Comment: The $ was making the cell reference absolute, by removing the $ the formulae was able to be copied across all relevant cells. Quite disappointed with the overall response on here people.